# Evaluate $\oint_L (x-y)dx+xydy$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$\oint_L (x-y)dx+xydy$$ where $ L\in \{x=a\cdot \cos ^3t,y=a \cdot \sin ^3t\}, 0\leq t \leq \Pi$ and $\{x=a\cdot \cos t,y=a\cdot \sin t\}, \Pi\leq t \leq 2\Pi $

So I try $$=\int_0^\Pi ((a\cdot \cos ^3t-a\cdot \sin ^3t)(-3a\cdot \cos ^2t\cdot \sin t)+a\cdot \cos ^3t\cdot a\cdot \sin ^3t\cdot 3\cdot a\cdot \sin ^2t\cdot \cos t)dt+\int_\Pi^{2\Pi} ((a\cdot \cos t-a\cdot \sin t)(-a\cdot \sin t)+a\cdot \cos t\cdot a\cdot \sin t\cdot a\cdot \cos t)dt$$
It looks pretty complicated, so I'm not sure it's a correct method.

Can I use Green's theorem in this task? I know that if it were a circle, I would simply parametrize the circle equation, which I understand \sin ce the curve consists of only one equation. However, \sin ce there are two equations, I'm not too sure how to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: Should $\Pi$ should be $\pi \approx 3.14$?

Comment: It should be $dx = -3a \cdot \cos^2 t \cdot \sin t$, not $-3a \cdot \cos^2 t \cdot \sin^2 t$.

Comment: Do you know [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Analyze your region. Fabulous theorem of Green works for any simple closed curve (not only a well-known parametrized circle). See Wikipedia.